# Can Springframework Controller be used for more than one function?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, methods, controller

I am new to Springframework and using version 2.5.6. Can I use the spring controller for more than one function.

I have add, edit, and delete functionality on my .jsp page. How can I handle these 3 requests through the same controller?

Comment: Since you are now starting, any chance of using the more recent version of Spring?

Comment: I am taking a Lab course, so I will have to follow the guidelines the instructor has provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Each function is a method in the controller class. You have to ensure that you map each action to a unique url.

```
    @RequestMapping("value="/mycontroller")
    @Controller
    public class MyController{

          @RequestMapping(value="edit")
          public String edit(){
               //your edit code
          }

           @RequestMapping(value="add")
           public String add(){
               //your add code
           }
    }
```

See [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/mvc.html) for some more examples.

Comment: thanks, but I am confused about how a controller would know about the type of request [add,edit or delete] it is getting?

Comment: It is determined by the URL mapping. When you request /mycontroller/edit the RequestDispatcher calls the edit() method, when you request /mycontroller/add the RequestDispatcher calls add() method.

Comment: I tried what you said but getting the following error:
<Error>
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /SpringGuestbook/guestbookController/add.app. Reason:

    Not Found
</Error>

Comment: So how is the class annotated? D you have a @RequestMapping(value="/guestbookController") annotation on the class itself? Is the method annotated with the @RequestMapping(value="add.app")?

Comment: yes it is. The functions in controller class are annotated as @RequestMapping(value="add.app") etc. and the class is annotated as @RequestMapping(value"guestbookController").
Even when I register add.app in app-servlet.xml, it works but doesn't enter in the add() function. It goes inside the onSubmit() function. Any idea?

Comment: If it invokes the unsubmit function then you probably need to look at the conditions under which the various functions are invoked. Spring MVC provides quite a few options. Try removing everything except the function that you wish and see what happens. If it works then you know that the other function has some condition that is matching before the requestmapping.

Comment: I removed all the functions from the controller and it was still calling the onsubmit function from the super.

Comment: Post your code so we can see it. Maybe there is something else to look for.